# Iterating through an array and returning parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm iterating through an array that was created from  constant. I am then performing some math on some of the values but seem to not be able to get them to display. I'm sure it is something relatively minor I am missing. I am just posting the code I am having trouble with but can post more if need be.

```
bitValue = document.getElementById("displayBits").value;

const selectedBit = selectedBits.find(bit => bit.name === bitValue);

var hardness;
var passDepth;
var numPass;
var feedRate;
var rpmBit;

for (var i = 0; i < selectedBit.length; i++) {
    if (selectedBit.rpm <= rpmValue) {
        rpmBit = rpmValue;
    }

    else { rpmBit = selectedBit.rpm }

    if (material.soft === true) {
        hardness = selectedBit.soft;
    }

    else { hardness = selectedBit.soft }

    if (selectedBit.ced <= thicknessValue) {
        passDepth = (Math.round(thicknessValue) / (Math.ceil(thicknessValue)) / selectedBit.ced);
        passDepth = (passDepth / selectedBit.flutes);
    }

    else {
        passDepth = selectedBit.ced;
    }

    numPass = (thicknessValue / passDepth);

    feedRate = (selectedBit.flutes * rpmBit * hardness);
}

console.log(selectedBit.name + numPass + feedRate + rpmValue + passDepth);
```

Comment: Its really difficult to understand code samples if they are not complete and runnable. [Minimal Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) make it far easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: I know, I kind of figured I would get that feed back but thought I would post first in the hopes that something jumped out right away. I figured I would edit afterwards to pair down the code to be able to post up. I did end it figuring it out. Had to walk away from pc for a few hours and the figured it out almost immediately. Had to reset myself I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I figured it out. My const is already iterated so no need to iterate a second time. Just had to revmove `(var i = 0; i < selectedBit.length; i++) { }` and it works.